# Copy specific columns from other Sheet to current Sheet where Row is determined by search (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sheets in an excel file. In the first sheet I have a column "types", and in the second sheet there are more information to different "types". 
For each row, I want to have excel search the type, which is specified in, say, the first column, in the "type sheet" (sheet 2) and to include columns from this sheet to the rows in my first sheet.

I was thinking this could be done maybe with VLOOKUP, but didn't find out how to get this to work.

Comment: To improve the chances of getting answers, and the quality of the answers, please [edit] your questions to include What version of Excel you have. Also tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Type this into the top cell and then copy and paste it down the column
    `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2)`

(You will have to replace the column letters and column index with the right ones.)

Comment: You're right, the thing may first attempts did not work was that the fixed $'s after Sheet2! seem to be crucial for VLOOKUP to work